# Compare three results with statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I am doing an analysis on the time it took for a group to do the same task on three different websites. I got the time it took on each website and I am trying to measure if there is a significant difference between the groups.

Looks like all tools require several lines of data and I already have the means per website.

```
Web A   Web B   Web C
00:27   00:23   00:21
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on what to do now?

Comment: You can't use just the means. You need to have the variability in time for each website. Hence the need for "several lines of data".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could I use a chi square by considering the average time as expected value? I think NOT because this is time but I want to make sure there is no other alternative

Comment: No.  There's no way to make chi-square work for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you were prepared to use a specific parametric assumption (in particular one indexed by a single parameter) where the mean was a sufficient statistic *and* you knew the sample sizes involved in each mean, you could write a likelihood from that, and so perhaps obtain a useful test that way.

One commonly used example for *times* would be the exponential distribution. One difficulty is that you have no real way to assess whether this assumption is reasonable because you have summarized away the information that would let you check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough observations you can use a non-parametric comparison of means via ranks  (Kruskal-Wallis test). If you check the data for normality first and nothing violates the assumption, this is the classical scenario for ANOVA.